# Is there a method to prevent PowerBI visual displaying results when record count is under 5?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a real world problem that has me stumped. I have a powerBI report that is list of employee survey answers. Before I share it with the firm, I need to make sure that no individual can be identified by simply playing with the slicers ("Marketing director in California hates management... we only have one marketing director in California).

Is there a function or a workaround I can use to either prevent the visuals from updating when the count of records is below 5 or to display a message "count of records too low, broaden your selection.

Whoever helps me with this, gets a case of beer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example :

```
Measure = IF(SUM(CV19Fact[Value])<800000,
"count of records too low, broaden your selection",
SUM(CV19Fact[Value]))
```

I created a measure and I am filtering the number of active Covid-19 cases by countries.
When choosing **"Yemen"**, the result is **"count of records too low, broaden your selection"**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot. Message me at milan AT vrekic.com and let me know where I can paypal cash for the beer :)